# Easy way to make a copy of a Type object

Tags: c#

I need to find a way to make a copy of an object of type `Type`. I have some code that make copy of object and lots of those object have properties of type `Type`. I cannot simply do an equal otherwise the reference will be the same and down the line a couple of these copies objects will have these property modified but it must not update the other ones so it has to be a new value.

So here's a very basic example class and behavior

```
public class A
{
    public int Quantity { get; set; } = 0;
    public Type ConnectionType { get; set; } = null;
    public A Copy()
    {
        var copy = new A();
        copy.Quantity = Quantity;
        copy.ConnectionType = ???
    }
}
```

My idea was simple, I told myself "Hey let's just hack this quickly and instantiate an object of that type and grab it's GetType()"

So I tried this :

```
public A Copy()
{
    var copy = new A();
    copy.Quantity = Quantity;
    var copyType = Activator.CreateInstance(ConnectionType).GetType();
    copy.ConnectionType = copyType;
}
```

Don't get me wrong this works for a very handful of classes. The problem is that the different Type that is passed in that property do not all have default constructor. The class are also not all developed internally and are changing once or twice a week.

Is there any way to copy the `Type` class without resorting on `Activator.CreateInstance`.

Obviously this is a very small sample. In reality I have many properties of type `Type` in thousands of object and the real code actually use a lot of reflection and this particular property execute such code if the `PropertyInfo.PropertyType` is `Type`.

Comment: I'm completely confused: `Type` is a .Net library class which identifies a whole type. You can't clone it, it makes no sense to do so. What exactly do you do with that `Type` object that you think it matters if it's a clone or not?

Comment: @Charlieface The `Type` are used into conditions, sometime are used to instanciate an object of that type it all depends on many many conditions. Typically external code will know things like if it has Class A with 5 class B that A.PropertyTypeX has to be once of those 50 Types

Comment: You're still not telling me why it matters if it's cloned or not?

Comment: @Charlieface In the project specification the clients will be modifying the Type property so I need to make a clone or else modifying 1 object reference will modify the second one as well

Comment: You can't modify a `Type` object, it has no mutable properties. You can modify the property to refer to different `Type` objects, however that will not affect other objects that refer to other `Type`s. The problem that you claim to have simply doesn't exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will always be only one `Type` for each class, so you can safely assign it.

[Excerpt from Object.GetType:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gettype?view=net-5.0)

> For two objects x and y that have identical runtime types, Object.ReferenceEquals(x.GetType(),y.GetType()) returns true.

So there is no way that two `Type` instances could exist for any given class, there will always be only one (`ReferenceEquals` **cannot** be overriden)

In your case you could just do:

```cs
copy.ConnectionType = ConnectionType;
```

Full example:

```cs
public class A
{
    public int Quantity { get; set; } = 0;
    public Type ConnectionType { get; set; } = null;
    public A Copy()
    {
        var copy = new A();
        copy.Quantity = Quantity;
        copy.ConnectionType = ConnectionType;
        return copy;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did try that at first but it was having the same reference in 2 classes but I just figured out it wasn't working because I was setting it from the same object. If I always set the original object with a new instance of `Type` I am always good on the copy.

Answer (score 0):

`Activator.CreateInstance(ConnectionType).GetType()` should return the same instance of `Type`. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gettype?view=net-5.0#remarks):

> For two objects `x` and `y` that have identical runtime types, `Object.ReferenceEquals(x.GetType(),y.GetType())` returns true.

So there is no point to use `Activator.CreateInstance` approach - simple shallow copying will have the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

`Type` objects are immutable. You can treat immutable types (like `string`) as if they were value types. Therefore, making a clone is not necessary.

Also, you cannot create and initialize `Type` objects yourself, nor can you clone them.

Comment: I was unaware they were immutable. I doesn't state that fact on the MSDN. I figured that being a class it was mutable

Comment: Well, it is not stated, but all properties are getter-only and the methods are of type `GetXy`, so, you cannot change anything. `string` is also a class and you cannot change a string, you can only create new strings being different from the original, but the original remains unchanged in every string operation.